# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: Ipython Matplotlib inline visualization: graphs are not plotted

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, inline, ubuntu-18.04

I am working in Ubuntu 18.04. - Linux distro.
When I use Python I have no problem producing my graphs, tables and plots output.
When I switch to IPython instead of the expected table I get

Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes

This is the script I am using from Dr. Hilpisch Python for finance O'Reilly books

Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.18.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import matplotlib as mpl

In [2]: mpl.**version**
Out[2]: '3.3.2'

In [3]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [4]: plt.style.use('seaborn')

In [5]: mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'

In [6]: %matplotlib inline

In [7]: import numpy as np

In [8]: np.random.seed(1000)

In [9]: y = np.random.standard_normal(20)

In [10]: x = np.arange(len(y))

In [11]: plt.plot(x, y);

Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes

Thank You for your help

Comment: maybe `plt.show()`?

Comment: That works when I am in Python. Not with  Ipython.